# trying to save credentials of ssh login gives a Load key "/Users/uname/.ssh/id_rsa": Is a directory error

Tags: macos, ssh

I have a file called "mykey.pub" in `/Users/uname/.ssh/id_rsa`

I created it with: `ssh-keygen`

I did (from inside the .ssh directory)

```
sudo ssh-copy-id -f -i id_rsa/mykey.pub mykey@host
```

When I try to do

```
ssh mykey@host
```

I get this error:  "Load key "/Users/uname/.ssh/id_rsa": Is a directory error

Answer (score 2):

From [`man 1 ssh`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#i) [emphasis mine]:

> `-i identity_file`
>   Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for public key authentication is read. The default is `~/.ssh/id_dsa`, `~/.ssh/id_ecdsa`, `~/.ssh/id_ed25519` and **`~/.ssh/id_rsa`**.

And from [`man 1 ssh-keygen`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen#FILES):

> `~/.ssh/id_rsa`
>   Contains the DSA, ECDSA, Ed25519 or RSA authentication identity of the user. This **file** should not be readable by anyone but the user.

This means `~/.ssh/id_rsa` should *not* be a directory. It should be your private key. The error is because `ssh` expects to find a file there.

Along with `id_rsa` I also have `id_rsa.pub` in the `.ssh` directory. The latter is my corresponding public key.

If your public key is `/Users/uname/.ssh/id_rsa/mykey.pub` then maybe your private key is `/Users/uname/.ssh/id_rsa/mykey`. If so, you may select this particular file while invoking `ssh`:

```
ssh -i /Users/uname/.ssh/id_rsa/mykey …
```

(where `…` denotes the rest of the command); or specify it in `~/.ssh/config` with `IdentityFile` keyword (see `man 5 ssh_config`). If you point `ssh` to the right file then it shouldn't matter `/Users/uname/.ssh/id_rsa` is a directory.

If I were you, I would rather rename the troublesome directory and place my default pair of RSA keys (if any) as `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. Then I would use `-i` or `IdentityFile` to select a non-default key if needed.